# Unit Test of WPF Application fails with NotSupportedException "The Uri prefix is not recognized"

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, nunit

I'm currently writing unit tests and at this position the tests fails with a NotSupportedException "The URI prefix is not recognized" After small research I have registered the "pack" Uri scheme, but it dosn't helps.

```
return _WaitImageThumbnail ?? (_WaitImageThumbnail = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/images/DefaultThumbnailLoading.png")));
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.CreateRequest(Uri uri)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest.GetRequest(Boolean allowPseudoRequest)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
   at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.CreateRequestAndGetResponse(Uri uri)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage..ctor(Uri uriSource, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage..ctor(Uri uriSource)
   ...
```

**Question:**
How can I load the image, and why this exception occurs?

Comment: see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523274/unit-testing-wpf-application-with-siteoforigin-pack-uri

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things you will have to do in order to load the image for your unit test.

### Register the Pack Uri or initialize WPF Application instance

You can register the pack URI as per the previous SO question [*Pack Urls and Unit Testing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710776/pack-urls-and-unit-testing-problem-with-my-environment) or initialize a WPF Application which will register the WPF framework components for you.  I typically do this during the assembly initialization stage.

```
   [AssemblyInitialize]
   public static void InitializeTestAssembly(TestContext ctx)
   {
       if (Application.Current == null)
           new Application();
   }
```

### Embed the Image as a Resource or Setup as Deployment Item

In order to use the pack uri as you've outlined above, the image must be set as a Resource so that it gets baked into your assembly. If you're not using as a Resource, change it to Content that gets copied to the output directory and then configure the test environment to deploy the image with the test:

```
 [DeploymentItem("/images/DefaultThumbnailLoading.png")]
 [TestMethod]
 public void WhenPerformingLongOperation_ShouldDisbleProgressIndicator()
 {
    // test here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @bryanbcook for the answer, but how can I determine where is the `BitmapImage` object really looking by loading the uri?

Comment: It should be relative to the application root, which in this case (MSTest) is the test-run folder (subfolder to TestResults). Consult the pack Uri syntax for specifics (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=VS.85).aspx). Looking at the example above, the image should be embedded in the MyAssemblyName assembly under the images folder.