# Uri not working in Unit Test Solution WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, uri

I have a solution where I have two projects. The first project has reference to the second one, and I use a Uri to get some ResourceDictionaries from the second one like this:

```
var disabledButtonStyle = new ResourceDictionary();
            disabledButtonStyle.Source = new Uri(@"/DayGreenTheme;component/DisabledSampleButtonStyle.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

I have a new solution for the unit tests, where I have reference to both of the projects dlls. When I wanted to run the test I got the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.CreateRequest(Uri uri)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest.GetRequest(Boolean allowPseudoRequest)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
   at ViewModels.FormParentViewModel.LoadResources() in c:\Project\Source\Cyclops\ViewModels\FormParentViewModel.cs:line 155
   at ViewModels.FormParentViewModel..ctor(IBaseViewModel generalViewModel, IBaseViewModel childViewModel) in c:\Project\Source\Cyclops\ViewModels\FormParentViewModel.cs:line 94
   at ViewModels.ConsumableViewModel..ctor(ILoadingBayLoadingManager loadingBayLoadingManager, IConsumableLoadingManager consumableLoadingManager, IConsumableDataViewModel consumableData, IDishPrepViewModel dishPrep, ITaskManager taskManager, IDishManager dishManager) in c:\Project\Source\Cyclops\ViewModels\ConsumableViewModel.cs:line 166
   at ViewModelsUnitTests.ConsumableViewModelUnitTests.TestSetup() in c:\Project\Source\CyclopsUnitTests\ViewModelsUnitTests\ConsumableViewModelUnitTests.cs:line 31
```

If I correct the Uris to be absolute it works, but I want to know if there is another, better solution.

Comment: If I use it without the UriKind I get UriFormatException.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14216297/1136211

Comment: Yes that was my bad, but it still gives the NotSupportedException in the unit test solution.